# How to slow down an object following an animated path?

Tags: objects, path

I was wondering on how to slow down the speed of an object following a path (that has been animated.) I'm trying to slow down how fast the UFO (with a particle system) goes along the bezier circle I've made, but I can't seem to find that option.

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23311/cyclic-orbit-animation/23384#23384

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, found it! If you click the bezier curve (or circle in this case) and go to the Data tab, scroll down to see Path Animation, and increase the frames which decreases the speed.

Answer (score 1):

With the path selected, in *properties* panel, in *curve* tab, *Path animation* section, you keyframed the *Evaluation time*.

In graph editor you can select the *Evaluation time* curve and scale it frame-wise with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> and enter any number you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however when I select the path, it only has a red line that can't be edited, unlike yours which has a yellow editable line.

Comment: you keyframed the evaluation time too?

Answer (score 1):

Parenting an object to a path keyframes and locks the evaluation time automatically. In graph editor, select evaluation time and look at its modifiers. Underneath "Expanded polynomial," activate "Additive." This should allow you to use keyframes to control the speed of the object on the path. You need not keyframe the frame count of the animation.