# How do I make a path animation last longer than 100 frames?

Tags: path

I've got a simple animation that lasts 250 frames and I am trying to create another animation within it but the "Parenting the object to the curve with the Follow Path" option stops after 100 frames - I've seen a similar question being answered here: [Cyclic orbit animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23311/cyclic-orbit-animation) but I am using version 2.82a which is very different from the demonstration given in that answer - can anyone give an updated answer?

Comment: Nohting has changed really, All of the anwers on that page are still workable in 2.8 what part are you struggling with?

Comment: Once you've given your object its Follow Path Constraint and animate it, select the curve, go in the Properties panel > Object Data tab > Path Animation, and change the Frames value

Comment: Ahh I see I’ve sorted it - thank you!!